# How to use lapply and convert back to int format in R function?

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I have quiz data that I would like to score in R, so I wrote a ScoreQuiz function:

```
ScoreQuiz <- function(x) {
  
  #Q1 Ans: C; Q2 Ans: D
  x$Q1_Score <-  lapply(x[,"Q1"], function(x) {as.integer(x == "C")} )
  x$Q2_Score <-  lapply(x[,"Q2"], function(x) {as.integer(x == "D")} )

  ## Doesn't work
  ## x$Q1_Score <- unlist(x$Q1_Score)

  score.list <- c("Q1_Score", "Q2_Score")
  
  # commented because of error
  #x$Total_Score <- apply(x[score.list], 1, sum)
  
  return(x)
  
} 

df <- data.frame("SubID" = 1:12, "Q1" = c("A","C","D"), "Q2"= c("D","A","B"))    
ScoreQuiz(df)
```

Turns out

```
 x$Q1_Score <-  lapply(x[,"Q1"], function(x) {as.integer(x == "C")} )
```

returns a list

```
$ Q1_Score:List of 12
  ..$ : int 0
  ..$ : int 1
```

So I cannot compute the Total Score inside the function.
However, I can unlist outside of the function and then compute the total score.

Is it possible to unlist inside the function, or better still, get I get Q1_Score without using a list in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `lapply` in this case :

```
ScoreQuiz <- function(x) {
  x$Q1_Score <-  as.integer(x$Q1 == 'C')
  x$Q2_Score <-  as.integer(x$Q2 == 'D')
  return(x)
} 

str(ScoreQuiz(df))

#'data.frame':  12 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ SubID   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ Q1      : chr  "A" "C" "D" "A" ...
# $ Q2      : chr  "D" "A" "B" "D" ...
# $ Q1_Score: int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
# $ Q2_Score: int  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
```